# How to make the system status bar completely disappear on an Android device

Tags: flutter, android-13, oneplusx

I am trying to create a full-screen widget in Flutter, where both the system status bar at the top and the navigation bar at the bottom are hidden. According to the information I could find you can achieve this by calling `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode`.

However, when I test the app on my device (OnePlus 8 Pro, Oxygen OS 13.1, Android 13), I don't get the behaviour that I expect. If the status bar is not hidden, then the app takes up the entire height of the screen, and the status bar is overlaid on top of it:
[image: Status bar is not hidden]

When I hide the status bar the status bar icons disappear, but a black bar appears instead, which seems to be the same height as the status bar:
[image: Status bar is hidden]

I have no problems with hiding the bottom navigation bar.

I tried to use:
`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky)` and

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
   SystemUiMode.manual,
   overlays: [],
)
```

I thought maybe the specific widget that I used caused the problem, so tested it with `SafeArea`, `Scaffold`, `Container` and `Card`, but get always get the same result.

I have created a simple app to demonstrate the behaviour:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

enum SystemUIOptions { all, statusBar, navigationBar, immersiveSticky }

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized;
  runApp(const SystemChromeTester());
}

class SystemChromeTester extends StatefulWidget {
  const SystemChromeTester({super.key});

  @override
  State<SystemChromeTester> createState() => _SystemChromeTesterState();
}

class _SystemChromeTesterState extends State<SystemChromeTester> {
  SystemUIOptions? selectedUIOption = SystemUIOptions.all;

  void printViewInsets() {
    print('System UI option: ${selectedUIOption!.name}');
    print('Height: ${MediaQuery.of(context).size.height}');
    print('Viewinsets top: ${MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.top}');
    print('Viewinsets bottom: ${MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom}');
    print('Viewpadding: ${MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding}');
    print('Padding: ${MediaQuery.of(context).padding}');
  }

  void toggleSystemUI(SystemUIOptions? selected) {
    switch (selected) {
      case SystemUIOptions.all:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
            overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
        break;
      case SystemUIOptions.statusBar:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
            overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top]);
        break;
      case SystemUIOptions.navigationBar:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
          SystemUiMode.manual,
          overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.bottom],
        );
        break;
      case SystemUIOptions.immersiveSticky:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
        break;
      default:
        SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual,
            overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top, SystemUiOverlay.bottom]);
    }
    setState(() {
      selectedUIOption = selected;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    printViewInsets();
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        // appBar: AppBar(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              RadioListTile(
                title:
                    const Text('Top (status bar) and bottom (navigation bar)'),
                value: SystemUIOptions.all,
                groupValue: selectedUIOption,
                onChanged: toggleSystemUI,
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                title: const Text('Top (status bar) only'),
                value: SystemUIOptions.statusBar,
                groupValue: selectedUIOption,
                onChanged: toggleSystemUI,
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                title: const Text('Bottom (navigation bar) only'),
                value: SystemUIOptions.navigationBar,
                groupValue: selectedUIOption,
                onChanged: toggleSystemUI,
              ),
              RadioListTile(
                title: const Text('Immersive sticky'),
                value: SystemUIOptions.immersiveSticky,
                groupValue: selectedUIOption,
                onChanged: toggleSystemUI,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is this a Flutter bug, is it specific to the device/OS I am using, or am I missing something obvious?